# Bloom Filter Index on Delta Table

Tags: hive, databricks, delta-lake, bloom-filter

Is is possible to create a Bloom filter index in Databricks on a Delta table using the filepath and not on the hive table referencing to that file location?

I tried the following:

```
CREATE BLOOMFILTER INDEX 
ON TABLE delta.'gs://GCS_Bucket/Delta_Folder_Path'
FOR COLUMNS(colname OPTIONS(fpp=0.1, numItems=100))
```

But it doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input 'CREATE BLOOMFILTER'(line 1, pos 7)

== SQL ==
CREATE BLOOMFILTER INDEX 
-------^^^
ON TABLE delta.'gs://GCS_Bucket/Delta_Folder_Path'
FOR COLUMNS(LOT_W OPTIONS(fpp=0.1, numItems=100))
```

Replacing the *delta.'gs://GCS_Bucket/Delta_Folder_Path'* with a hive external table that references the file works as expected.

All the examples that I found first create a table of it, and then create the bloom filter index. But this is not what we want.

We only want to have tables that are in the gold layer and some in silver available in hive. The table that I want to add a bloom filter index on should not be in hive.

**Edit:** This is on Databricks runtime 10.4 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably error is arising because you're using ordinary quotes instead of backquotes for path ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-names.html#table-name)). Try:

```sql
CREATE BLOOMFILTER INDEX 
ON TABLE delta.`gs://GCS_Bucket/Delta_Folder_Path`
FOR COLUMNS(colname OPTIONS(fpp=0.1, numItems=100))
```

P.S. Error message points to the incorrect place, I think that it's known issue

Comment: You are right. I changed the quotes to backquotes and it worked. Stupid mistake. A vacuum or optimized always worked with normal quotes. Didn't know about the backquotes. (PS, your example code still shows the normal quotes instead of backquotes)

Comment: oh, sorry - I forgot to update your example, fixed